# Java Compilation Error with Method overloading

Tags: java, overloading

What would be the best way to achieve ***testCall2*** below without doing explicit parsing ***(Sub1) in***?

```
class Super {
}

class Sub1 extends Super {
}

class Sub2 extends Super {
}

public void testCall2(Super in) {
    testCall(in);        // <~~~ Compilation Error 

}

public void testCall(Sub1 sub) {

}

public void testCall(Sub2 sub) {

}
```

Comment: Which `testCall` would you like to be invoked?

Comment: You'll first need to move those methods inside classes to get this to compile. In Java, methods can only exist inside classes.

Comment: Just one of them, depends on the instanceOf in. However, the point is I don't want to use instanceOf or any explicit casting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to refactor and use polymorphism. Declare the `testCall` method in `Super`

```
class Super {
    public void testCall() {}
}
```

and implement it in the subclasses.

Then invoke it

```
public void testCall2(Super in) {
    in.testCall(); 
}
```

Otherwise you'll have to use a cast to transform the value's type to a type expected by either of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it will give compile time error because you are creating methods out of class body. your all methods are out of class body..

```
class Super {
}

class Sub1 extends Super {
}

class Sub2 extends Super {
}// your all three classes are started and ended immediately

public void testCall2(Super in) {
    testCall(in);        // <~~~ Compilation Error 

}

public void testCall(Sub1 sub) {

}

public void testCall(Sub2 sub) {

}
//and all three methods are defined out of any  class body.
```